# How can I repeat the Specific row headers of table in iTextSharp

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, itext

`PdfPTable.HeaderRows` property to the number of rows which gives you the entire all the three rows..

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(11);
table.DefaultCell.Padding = 11;
table.WidthPercentage = 96;
table.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;
table.SplitLate = false;
table.SplitRows = true;
table.HeaderRows =3;`
```

the above code returning all the first three rows for the repeated pages as header...but i want to repeat only  the third row only as header...

Comment: You are already nesting the tables (otherwise you won't call your table `innertable`). Why don't you add the two rows that you don't want to repeat to the outer table? That way you only need to repeat 1 header row.

Comment: K i have changed the table name..i want the third row alone should be repeated..

Comment: Well that's not possible with `PdfPTable`. You'll have to work around it.